# ListViewItem is not "GUI" selected when within a tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ListView` within a `TabControl`. When adding and selecting an item, code wise:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "LV1";
listView1.Items.Add(item);

listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

It does get selected, but it does **not** turn blue (as in GUI selected). I've already tried `listView1.Focus();` after the selection, but no avail.

Is there any way to get this working properly? This "bug" only happens when the `ListView` inside a `TabControl`, when it's not it works properly.

Comment: Focus() doesn't work if the control isn't yet visible.  Use Select() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, works :) Please post an answer so I can mark it :-)

Comment: I upvoted Sekai's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView1.Select();
listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```